# Problem Nexus 1 running apps on my phone from Eclipse

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Google Nexus S. Great phone.

I have been developing apps on it, not too much of a problem.

Since last week I can suddenly not run apps from Eclipse on the phone anymore. I get the following error:

```
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] Android Launch!
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] Performing com.xxx.android.imagebrowser.ImageBrowser activity launch
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] Automatic Target Mode: using device '34315B519D6000EC'
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] Uploading ImageBrowser.apk onto device '34315B519D6000EC'
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] Failed to install ImageBrowser.apk on device '34315B519D6000EC': An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[2011-04-11 20:12:48 - ImageBrowser] Launch canceled!
```

I am going out of my mind. Everything has been working perfectly before. I have tried just running a Hello world app with the same problem.

My Machine: Apple i5, pretty standard.
OS: Windows 7 32 bit
Eclipse: Helios Service Release 2
ADB: Android debug birdge version 1.0.26
I have re-installed the google usb drivers as per this following link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
USB debugging enabled on phone

I have hard factory reset my phone in case something is wrong.

I am at wits end. Everything worked just fine, and then it all suddenly went berserk and now nothing works.

2 things: about a week ago I plugged in an ipod which had been in someones windows machine and it appeared to have a virus on it. I have run AVG and removed one or 2 things that were on there, but has not helped.

Secondly I have a 3g dongle I use for internet, and that connects via usb. But I have been using this together with the phone no problem...

When I plug in the phone, it immediately appears in Eclipse in the devices panel, and it is online and showing Honeycomb android version. Then, when I hit run, the above message/error occurs and then immediately the device is offline. I can only unplug and plug in again, and start from the beginning with same results.

Very oddly, I have had issues when disabling USB debugging, and trying to copy photos from my phone. When I enabled the device as USB storage, it woudl connect fine, but not always stay on as stable. If I then went to the images folder, it would disconnect. Extremely odd.

Help???

Comment: Are you using windows 7 64 bit? I have a dual boot win7x64/ubuntu on my machine and I can't get it to work w/ windows but it works great in ubuntu. It could be a problem with windows.

Comment: @Stephen: I have Windows 7 x64 and have it working perfectly.

Comment: hi I just made sure , its 32 bit (I have 4gb ram but its only using 2.18Gb..stupid I know.) What is the weirdest is this worked perfectly for about a month. Not a hitch or glitch, but suddenyl since a few days it's just gone totally bonkers.

Comment: Joseph - do you have a google nexus S? When you are in usb storage mode can you access the photos folder no problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the your log, the issue is `An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`.

So it wasn't caused by 1) a physical loss of connection or 2) the device itself.

The issue therefore lies with your computer. Have you tried:

1. Performing a full system scan with at least one different anti-virus package
2. Disabling the active-scanning of your anti-virus software while copying
3. Re-installing ADB
4. As a last resort: re-installing Eclipse and the Android SDK/AVD

Comment: sorry, cut short my comment. As for point 2 - while copying? what do you mean by this? Point 3, yes well I will try that now perhaps. I still have a query about the issue I have ALWAYS had - copying photos from the device. I tried using a usb extension the other day and then nothing worked. Also, I have always had problems with loss of connection while trying to copy photos. I have suspected my usb ports on my mac are finicky? I think I will try another usb cable first to see if that might help?

Comment: Just try to install it once with the anti-virus disabled, occasionally they can be *anal*. Possibly - try with a friends computer if you can.

Comment: ok. So I just used a friends little laptop. I plug in my nexus S, and allow the device to enable usb storage and voila. I can go and browse images on my phone. Same cable, same phone.

Comment: oops...entered again. THen I search around for macbook pro (the computer I use to develop) USB problems and it seems stacks of people have issues with them. Now someone might take this personally but I have to admit, I paid twice as much for apple mac, and so far it's been a piece of sh!t. performance is very average, battery life is nowhere near supposed 7 hours (even using macos, even using all battery saving etc) its maybe 3.5 hours, and now this issue with the usb. I'm selling it. Gnna install my dev environment on another pc tomorrow and try and do some work. 12 hours wasted. Thanks apple

Comment: COnfirmed. I bought a powered usb hub and all problems solved. Also, my 3G connection has improved. Data rates on mem sticks have imrpoved dramatically.

Comment: I hate to say it but I won't buy an Apple again. To sell hardware at such a premium then have problems with it is not really on. I also took it to the apple store and explained the problem to be met with blank stares. I emailed various departments in Apple about this and zero response. It cannot be ignored that thousands of ppl complain about usb problems...Apple needs to sort it out. But I will not buy their stuff again, as nice as it is...stylish etc, the reliability so far has been a serious let down. cheers all